# How can a user enter a password which is encrypted? PYTHON3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, encryption, hash

I have encrypted a PIN password onto a database. I have done this using hash, and save the PIN which is entered under the variable actualPIN:

```
 actualPIN = str(actualPIN)
    PIN = hashlib.md5() 
    PIN.update((actualPIN).encode('utf-8'))
    data = (rollingBalance, actualPIN, ID)
    print(rollingBalance)
    with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = 'update Atm set Balance=?, PIN=? where CustomerID=?'
        cursor.execute(sql, data)
        db.commit()
```

Now, this works fine and saves the encrypted PIN to the database as '81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055' which is an encryption for '1234'(The default PIN before changing the pin is 9999, and it is saved as 9999 on the database originally). Now, when I go back to the start and try to enter the pin '1234' I am told this is invalid, and the actual pin is the encryption provided above. My guess at the moment is to change my code for entering the pin to try and make this match the encryption, but I'm not sure if this is correct, as I don't know how to decrypt a  message. The code for entering the PIN on the database is as follows:

```
with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select Balance from Atm where CustomerID=?",(ID,))
            balance = cursor.fetchone()
            rollingBalance = (balance[0])
        print("You must now enter in your PIN")
        with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select PIN from Atm where CustomerID=?",(ID,))
            PIN = cursor.fetchone()
            actualPIN = (PIN[0]) 
        print(actualPIN)
        loggedIN = False
        while loggedIN == False:
            answer = (input("Please enter your pin"))
            if answer == str(actualPIN):
                loggedIN = True
                mainMenu(name, ID, rollingBalance, actualPIN)
            else:
                print("That is incorrect")
```

Comment: when user enters `1234` you encrypt it, and compare encrypted result with what you have stored in your db

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want as output. If you want to identify the customer based on the pin, your request `select Balance from Atm where CustomerID=?",(ID,)` is incorrect. It should be `Select CustomerID from Atm where PIN=?` with ? being your hash. If this is the case, pay attention that multiple customers can have the idea of using the same pass (e.g 1234). You should also ask another identifier (kind of login) and try to match both. In the current case, if customerA is registered first and customerB set the same PIN, when customer B will try to connect, he will be logged as customerA

Comment: Thanks Igor! Don't worry Nicolas, that was for another bit, but thank you anyway!